# This simple user control code crashes VS2015. Have no idea why

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crash

```
public partial class displayvoltage : UserControl
{
    public displayvoltage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!this.ratio_1.Checked && !this.ratio_12.Checked && !this.ratio_34.Checked && !this.ratio_14.Checked)
            this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
    }

    public double Ratio
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ratio_1.Checked) return 1.0;
            if (this.ratio_1.Checked) return 4.0 / 3.0;
            if (this.ratio_1.Checked) return 2.0;
            return 4.0;
        }
    }

    public int SetRatio
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == 1) this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
            if (value == 2) this.ratio_34.Checked = true;
            if (value == 3) this.ratio_12.Checked = true;
            if (value == 4) this.ratio_14.Checked = true;
            SetRatio = value;
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(0.0)]
    public double Voltage
    {
        get { return Voltage * this.Ratio; }
        set { Voltage = value; }
    }

    private bool DisplayVoltage = false;
    private bool Pause = false;

    private void ratio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)sender;

        if (r.Checked) Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Created with the designer just 4 radios and one panel.
Even if I want to display properties of the control VS crashes, if I start the program it crashes. What can be the problem?

Can I have a property with get only?

Comment: You are going to create stack overflow exceptions in SetRatio and Voltage. When VS loads your control, its executing this code and the OS is going to shut it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a few reasons, but most likely it is because this is causing an infinite loop which causes a StackOverflow:

```
public int SetRatio
{
    set
    {
        if (value == 1) this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
        if (value == 2) this.ratio_34.Checked = true;
        if (value == 3) this.ratio_12.Checked = true;
        if (value == 4) this.ratio_14.Checked = true;
        SetRatio = value;
    }
}
```

The last line SetRatio could be calling the SetRatio property setter which causes the code to execute again starting at:

```
 if (value == 1) this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
 if (value == 2) this.ratio_34.Checked = true;
 if (value == 3) this.ratio_12.Checked = true;
 if (value == 4) this.ratio_14.Checked = true;
 SetRatio = value;
```

And looping for ever. VS and .Net don't handle stack overflow and out of memory exceptions too well.

Try:

```
int setRatio;
public int SetRatio
{
    set
    {
        if (value == 1) this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
        if (value == 2) this.ratio_34.Checked = true;
        if (value == 3) this.ratio_12.Checked = true;
        if (value == 4) this.ratio_14.Checked = true;
        setRatio = value;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work try changing your constructor to see if that is causing the issue because controls with constructors that throw exceptions can cause VS to crash as well:

```
 public displayvoltage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //if (!this.ratio_1.Checked && !this.ratio_12.Checked && !this.ratio_34.Checked && !this.ratio_14.Checked)
    //    this.ratio_1.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: the constructor was causing the problem, It has started to crash even when I was only building the solution. Thank you.